# T-SQL Pivot query

Tags: t-sql, pivot

I have a table that contains a laserform name and a date e.g.

My table is called myBWB_LaserForms

```
laserform   editwhen
LRAP1.lpw   2009-09-03 16:06:00.000
CON29R.lpw  2009-10-29 12:35:00.000
UN1.lpw     2010-03-02 11:38:00.000
UN244.lpw   2012-04-19 12:14:00.000
LT3.lpw     2013-01-02 11:00:00.000
LRAP1.lpw   2007-12-10 15:34:00.000
```

What I am trying to produce is a report which has the name of the laserform down the left and years across the top e.g. 2004, 2005, 2006 and then each intersecting cell would have a count of the number of records for that form name for that particular year.

Normally I would do something like

```
select l.laserform,
(select count(*) from mybwb_laserforms l1 where l1.laserform=l.laserform and year(editwhen)=2004) AS [2004],
(select count(*) from mybwb_laserforms l2 where l2.laserform=l.laserform and year(editwhen)=2005) AS [2005],
(select count(*) from mybwb_laserforms l3 where l3.laserform=l.laserform and year(editwhen)=2006) AS [2006],
(select count(*) from mybwb_laserforms l4 where l4.laserform=l.laserform and year(editwhen)=2007) AS [2007]
from mybwb_laserforms l
group by l.laserform
order by l.laserform
```

However I realise that this is pretty horrible SQL and I should be much more intelligent about it.

I've been trying to learn how to use the pivot function but am struggling to get my head around it.

Also most examples I have found seem to have the columns of the query hard coded - it would be good if the pivot could be dynamic and get the unique year(editwhen) values so I don't have to modify the query next year and the year after that.

Answer (score 0):

Just sum it up.

```
select laserform,
sum(case when year(editwhen)=2004 then 1 else 0 end) AS [2004],
sum(case when year(editwhen)=2005 then 1 else 0 end) AS [2005],
sum(case when year(editwhen)=2006 then 1 else 0 end) AS [2006],
sum(case when year(editwhen)=2007 then 1 else 0 end) AS [2007]
from mybwb_laserforms
where year(editwhen) between 2004 and 2007
group by laserform
order by laserform
```

Or dynamic

```
declare @Year int = year(GetDate());
declare @Years TABLE ([year] varchar(4));
insert into @Years values (@Year-12),(@Year-11),(@Year-10),(@Year-9);

declare @SQLSums varchar(max) = '';
select @SQLSums = @SQLSums +char(13)+', sum(case when year(editwhen)='+[year]+' then 1 else 0 end) AS ['+[year]+']'
from @Years;

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max) = 'select laserform'+ @SQLSums +'
from mybwb_laserforms
group by laserform
where year(editwhen) between '+cast(@Year-12 as varchar)+' and '+cast(@Year-9 as varchar)+'
order by laserform';

--select @SQL;
exec (@SQL);
```